# Python Pandas optimization algorithm: compare datetime and retrieve datas

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, pandas

This post is quiet long and I will be very grateful to everybody who reads it until the end. :)

I am experimenting execution python code issues and would like to know if you have a better way of doing what I want to.
I explain my problem brifely. I have plenty solar panels measurements. Each one of them is done each 3 minutes. Unfortunately, some measurements can fail. The goal is to compare the time in order to keep only the values that have been measured in the same minutes and then retrieve them. A GUI is also included in my software, so each time the user changes the panels to compare, the calculation has to be done again. To do so, I have implemented 2 parts, the first one creates a vector of true or false for each panel for each minute, and the second compare the previous vector and keep only the common measures.

All the datas are contained in the pandas df energiesDatas. The relevant columns are:

- name: contains the name of the panel (length 1)
- date: contains the day of the measurement (length 1)
- list_time: contains a list of all time of measurement of a day (length N)
- list_energy_prod : contains the corresponding measures (length N)

The first part loop over all possible minutes from beginning to end of measurements. If a measure has been done, add True, otherwise add False.

```
self.ListCompare2=pd.DataFrame()    
for n in self.NameList:#loop over all my solar panels
    m=self.energiesDatas[self.energiesDatas['Name']==n]#all datas
    #table_date contains all the possible date from the 1st measure, with interval of 1 min.
    table_list=[1 for i in range(len(table_date))]
    pointerDate=0 #pointer to the current value of time
    #all the measures of a given day are transform into a str of hour-minutes
    DateString=[b.strftime('%H-%M') for b in m['list_time'].iloc[pointerDate] ]
    #some test
    changeDate=0
    count=0
    #store the current pointed date
    m_date=m['Date'].iloc[pointerDate]
    #for all possible time
    for curr_date in table_date:
        #if considered date is bigger, move pointer to next day
        while curr_date.date()>m_date:
            pointerDate+=1
            changeDate=1
            m_date=m['Date'].iloc[pointerDate]
        #if the day is changed, recalculate the measures of this new day
        if changeDate:
            DateString=[b.strftime('%H-%M') for b in m['list_time'].iloc[pointerDate] ]
            changeDate=0 
        #check if a measure has been done at the considered time
        table_list[count]=curr_date.strftime('%H-%M') in DateString
        count+=1
    #add to a dataframe
    self.ListCompare2[n]=table_list
        l2=self.ListCompare2
```

The second part is the following: given a "ListOfName" of modules to compare, check if they have been measured in the same time and only keep the values measure in the same minute.

```
ListToKeep=self.ListCompare2[ListOfName[0]]#take list of True or False done before
for i in ListOfName[1:]#for each other panels, check if True too
    ListToKeep=ListToKeep&self.ListCompare2[i]
for i in ListOfName:#for each module, recover values
    tmp=self.energiesDatas[self.energiesDatas['Name']==i]
    count=0
    #loop over value we want to keep (also energy produced and the interval of time)
    for j,k,l,m,n in zip(tmp['list_time'],tmp['Date'],tmp['list_energy_prod'],tmp['list_energy_rec'],tmp['list_interval']):
        #calculation of the index
        delta_day=(k-self.dt.date()).days*(18*60)
        #if the value of ListToKeep corresponding to the index is True, we keep the value 
        tmp['list_energy_prod'].iloc[count]=[ l[index] for index,a in enumerate(j) if ListToKeep.iloc[delta_day+(a.hour-4)*60+a.minute]==True]
        tmp['list_energy_rec'].iloc[count]=[ m[index] for index,a in enumerate(j) if ListToKeep.iloc[delta_day+(a.hour-4)*60+a.minute]==True]
        tmp['list_interval'].iloc[count]=[ n[index] for index,a in enumerate(j) if ListToKeep.iloc[delta_day+(a.hour-4)*60+a.minute]==True]
        count+=1

    self.store_compare=self.store_compare.append(tmp)
```

Actually, this part is the one that takes a very long time.

My question is: Is there a way to save time, using build-in function or anything.

Thank you very much

Kilian

Comment: Could you try to reduce the complexity of your example? Perhaps show a subset of the relevant data for the step that takes long?

Comment: @chris-sc Dear Chris, thank you for your consideration. I am aware it is a bit though. Here is a link to an example:http://s27.postimg.org/w2wb7ricj/example_python_stackoverlfow.png Sorry, but I cannot uploade image on the post yet

Comment: @chris-sc and here is the 1st part described above, http://s4.postimg.org/rxrr7dusd/example_python_stackoverlfow2.png . The 2nd part is taking the list_comp for the desired panels, multiply them, and then extract the corresponding datas (by this I mean the corresponding date) from the original dataframe. This part takes a lot of time because it loops over all the value and check if there is a 1 or 0. Thank you again

Comment: I believe your data structure isn't appropriate for your problem. Especially the `list` in fields of a `DataFrame`, they make loops or `apply` almost unavoidable. Could you in principle re-structure the data? (For example one `df` per solar panel with columns `date`, `time`, `energy`)

Comment: @chris-sc Yes I can do that easily. Do you think the for loop is slowing the software a lot? This will change a bit of my code. I will try it and let you know as soon as it is done. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer of chris-sc sloved my problem:

> I believe your data structure isn't appropriate for your problem. Especially the list in fields of a DataFrame, they make loops or apply almost unavoidable. Could you in principle re-structure the data? (For example one df per solar panel with columns date, time, energy)